# Invoking a Javascript from Lotus Notes on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, lotus-notes

I am building a Proof Of Concept for a component that was earlier built in vb6. Since the component has complex UI elements, I am not really sure how far i can reproduce the same thing with Lotus Notes UI elements. What I am now currently looking to do is the following.

1. Create a Button in an exist LN form.
2. When the button is clicked it invokes a javascript which will create a template (or load the htm dynamically) htm page with the necessary interface elements.
3. Use jQuery or Dojo to Ajaxify the interface and the http requests.
4. Once users click on a button on the htm page, return the select values to the form.
5. Unload the htm template and twiddle thumbs as if nothing happened.

First off, I am not sure if this possible, so is it possible ? If yes then can you guys give me any links to samples or samples which definitely will be helpful.

Btw this LN application on which i am building this component is not web enabled and is purely a LN desktop application.

Any help on this would appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke Javascript from within a normal Lotus Notes button, and it will run in the Lotus Notes client. However, the Notes client doesn't recognise *all* Javascript. For example, `document.write(...)` calls don't work.

If you have Domino Designer installed (and I presume you do!) then search Designer Help for "Table of supported JavaScript objects for automated components" -- that document may help identify what you can and can't do in the Notes client.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Search on "LOTUS NOTES" & AJAX . Richard Schwartz has some examples out there, and I think there are others.