# How to insert html file in lotus notes when a user click the image

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a image called "Send greeting card" in my HTML file. when a user clicks that image, it should open lotus notes and insert the html file. Any idea of doing this in HTML/Classic ASP.

Comment: have you looked into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099232/invoking-a-javascript-from-lotus-notes-on-click-of-a-button?rq=1

Comment: i already this checked this before i post a question. there is no proper answer for this question.